# i need help solving this sql syntax

Tags: sql

I was trying to inner join multiple tables that has similar columns even tho some of the other tables column has been specified, I wanted to include all of table a columns.

I kept getting errors saying there are matching columns in the tables and can not be included in a view.
What can I do?

I'm doing this, so I can load the files on SSIS to do error handling and export it to OLAP database

```sql
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Mortgage_view] AS
    SELECT
         a.*
        ,b.MonthlyIncome
        ,b.Bonuses
        ,b.Commission
        ,b.OtherIncome
        ,b.[Rent or  Own]
        ,b.Checking
        ,b.Savings
        ,b.RetirementFund
        ,b.MutualFund
        ,c.[Property City]
        ,c.[Property State]
        ,c.[Property Usage]
        ,c.[Property   Zip]
        ,c.Property_ID
        ,c.RealEstateAgentEmail
        ,c.RealEstateAgentName
        ,c.RealEstateAgentPhone
        ,d.Loan_ID
        ,d.[Purpose of Loan]
        ,d.LoanAmount
        ,d.[Purchase Price]
        ,d.CreditCardAuthorization
        ,d.[Number of Units]
        ,d.Refferal
        ,d.[Co-Borrower SSN]
    FROM Borrower_source AS a
    INNER JOIN Financial_source AS b
    INNER JOIN Property_source AS c
    INNER JOIN Loan_source AS d
    ON d.SSN = c.SSN
    ON c.SSN = b.SSN
    ON b.SSN = a.SSN
```

Comment: Please tag it with the relevant database.  All lower case text is hard to read.  Use triple (instead of single) backtick and format your query for readability.  Include the actual error message.  Minimize the query (for instance `create view` just add noise) and include the a minimal schema of the minimal number of tables that trigger the error.

Comment: The `ON` clause usually follows the `JOIN` directly, because it belongs to the join ("**join** the table xy **on** the condition that ..."): `INNER JOIN Financial_source AS b ON b.SSN = a.SSN INNER JOIN Property_source AS c ON c.SSN = b.SSN INNER JOIN Loan_source AS d ON d.SSN = c.SSN`.

Comment: A view cannot have multiple columns with the same name. So apparently your "a" table contains columns that are already mentioned for the others

Comment: On a side note: It looks a bit weird that you join all tables on the same column. Does every table have exactly one row for an SSN? If a table lacks such row you won't get the SSN in your results, and if more than one table has more than one row for an SSN, you may create some cartesian product joining rows that are not directly related.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: usually you are right, but this syntax also works, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=14d9d96204cb3f8d82bc314674bd7f2d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `select a.*`. You need to remove this and replace it with the *actual* columns you want from table `Borrower_source`.

If you actually want a column that has the same name as one you are already selecting from another table you will need to *alias* it to an alternative name.

For example, suppose the table also had a column *Refferal* (which btw is spelled *Referral*), you should have something like `select ..., a.refferal as BorrowerReferral, ...` .

The reason you have to do this is once you have created the *view* it can be used by another query as if it were a base-table.

Imagine a view that allowed you to have two columns, both named *Referral*, and you run the perfectly valid SQL `select Referral from Mortgage_view`. Which of the two (or more?!) columns named *Referral* do you mean?

Therefore every column name in a view - just like a base table - must be unique.

It would also help your query readability to associate the `join` condition with its join criteria, and also use *meaningful* table aliases. Since all are joining on the same value from `Borrower_source` you can simply use

```
from Borrower_source b
inner join Financial_source f on f.SSN = b.SSN
inner join Property_source p on p.SSN = b.SSN
inner join Loan_source l on l.SSN = b.SSN
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i think i can fix it from here on..really appreciate your detailed answer